# Nested Loops And Tuples

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

Im trying to get my code to print out each value on a new

```
cats = ("Tiger","Lion","Cheetah")
canids = ("Dog","Wolf","Fox")
reptiles = ("Snake","Crocodile","Iguana")
animals = (cats, canids,reptiles)
for i in animals:
    for j in [0,-1]:
        print(i[j])
```

but when i run it it doesn't include the second values of the lists,

```
Tiger
Cheetah
Dog
Fox
Snake
Iguana
```

Comment: What do you expect `for j in [0,-1]:` to do?

Comment: its not just the second value. you are iterating 0 and -1, that is the first and last element of your tuple index. Therefore, any elements in between  are not even considered!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to iterate over a range of index, you need to use `range`. Otherwise, `i` only takes the value `0` and `-1`.

```
for i in animals:
    for j in range(0, len(i)): # Note the use of `range` here
        print(i[j])
```

Although, since `i` is itself a `tuple` you can iterate over it directly. Here I renamed `i` to `family` for readability.

```
for family in animals:
    for animal in family:
        print(animal)
```

Both have the following output.

```
Tiger
Lion
Cheetah
Dog
Wolf
Fox
Snake
Crocodile
Iguana
```

Answer (score 2):

`j` will be `0` and `-1`, i.e. the first and last value when indexing a list.

You could simply

```
cats = ("Tiger", "Lion", "Cheetah")
canids = ("Dog", "Wolf", "Fox")
reptiles = ("Snake", "Crocodile", "Iguana")
animal_lists = (cats, canids, reptiles)
for animal_list in animal_lists:
    for animal in animal_list:
        print(animal)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) different iterables

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*animals))
```

Output

```
['Tiger',
 'Lion',
 'Cheetah',
 'Dog',
 'Wolf',
 'Fox',
 'Snake',
 'Crocodile',
 'Iguana']
```

Answer (score 1):

Most basic modification you can make to your code is simply changing these set of lines

```
for i in animals:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

Same concept others provided just minimal adjustments to what you already have.